# Practical usages for show create table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Reading some new functions on the mysql development documentation page, I come across what looks to be a gimmick and in  my eyes provide no practical usage. The function in question is

```
show create table tablename
```

which outputs how the table is actually constructed.. So the question is, how would this be useful in an actual productio mode? a function which shows how the table is created?

Possible scenarios:

Assist in automation of deployments for some PHP packages which rely on a database? Just stick to importing a .sql document on running the installation?

Create a new table on the fly via php? That's somewhat-bad practice imho

understandably this can be boiled down to the common response with asking `exec()` questions within PHP or other languages.

> if exec is your answer, you are asking the wrong questions

So the overall question, which might boil down to the above quote, is what practical usages will this `show create table` actually perform in a production state SQL Server?

*as most production servers import a .sql document when an updated package is released, this minimizing possible conflicts from manually importing and not configuring a datatable correctly on the production server*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show create table` is a convenient way to see column types, constraints, etc. It's helpful when trying to answer questions like "which fields on this table are indexed?" for example.

Comment: It's also usefull for debug sometimes. You can be sure that if you manage db with 2500+ tables you will use it pretty often :)